# Google Docs : save automaticlly shared doc

Tags: google-docs

I search a tip to save automaticly in my drive recente version of modified document ?

Thanks.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand. Do you want your google document to save automatically. Because by default it does that.

Comment: yes , but when a docuement is shared only to read , I want to have a copy evey time my partner make a change

Answer (score 0):

Have a look under File > See revision history. There you can see the 'Revision history'. It shows which changes were made, and by whom.

Comment: yes , but if my partner stop sharing this doc , can I have a last version in my drive ?

Comment: No, you will have to save the version you want, while you have at least view access.